# React Native зачем для локализации библиотеки?

Tags: react-native

Первый раз добрался до локализации.

Нашел парочку библиотек, но задумался - зачем они?

Например, создам объект:

```
var languages = {  
  ru:{
    menu:"Меню",
    addfav:"Добавить в избранное",
    removefav:"Убрать из избранного",
    choice:"Выбор"
  },
  en:{
    menu:"Menu",
    addfav:"Add to favorites",
    removefav:"Remove from favorites",
    choice:"Choice"
  }
};
```

А в тексте буду брать строки из другого объекта, в котором буду обновлять поля согласно языку.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: "Нашел парочку библиотек" - каких библиотек?

Comment: Библиотеки локализации нужны, что б выводить сообщения на разных языках, и текст сообщения удобно зашифровать и редактировать в файле(файлах) языка. В них есть особенности, например, если перевод отстутствует - может браться значение с "главного" языка. Так же может быть возможность переключить язык, может не быть. Главная, пожалуй, особенность - удобство и наличие интеграции с средой разработки.

Comment: Библиотеки, например: react-native-l20n, ReactNativeLocalization, i18n. Хм, из того что вы перечислили - вроде мой способ не хуже. При заполнении полей объекта я также могу указать заполнение из дефолтного языка, если значение отсутствует.
,